# Logout implementation within web api application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have implemented `Login` and `Logout` actions in my web api controller like this

**Login**

```
   [HttpPost] 
        [Route("Login")]
        public IHttpActionResult LoginUser(LoginUserBindingModel model)
        {
             var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var tokenServiceUrl = request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + request.ApplicationPath + "/Token";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", model.Username),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", model.Password)
            };
                var requestParamsFormUrlEncoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams);
                var tokenServiceResponse =  client.PostAsync(tokenServiceUrl, requestParamsFormUrlEncoded).Result;
                var responseString =  tokenServiceResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var responseCode = tokenServiceResponse.StatusCode;
                if (responseCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) return BadRequest();
                var responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(responseCode)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(responseString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };
                //ApplicationUser user =  UserManager.FindAsync("tester", "azerty123").Result;

                ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username).Result;


                if (user == null) return NotFound();
                ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType).Result;
                IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    //{ "userName", "tester" }
                    { "userName", model.Username }
                };
                AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties(data);

                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(properties);
                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(properties);

                Dictionary<string, object> account =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseString);


                return Ok(account);
            }
        }
```

**Logout**

```
 [Route("Logout")]
        [Authorize]
        public IHttpActionResult Logout()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            return Ok();
        }
```

The problem is that when I log in the application, then I get the token to consume some secured services.When I log out, the token still available and I still can consume the secured services.

So I need to know:

1. What is the reason of this problem?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you wrapping calls to your Token endpoint into another action method, only to set a cookie in a RESTful service? Why didn't you just use Cookies Authentication if that is what you want? You are merging those two approaches in a way that, frankly, is a very bad practice: OAuth is not meant to be used in this way. As an aside: tokens are self contained by default, of course it will still work until expired.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I wrap the token endpoint to make it shown in the documentation (help area). How can I make the token expired in the logout action if I'd like to use OAuth  ?

Comment: You can't. The only way to expire a token is to wait for it to expire. That's why access tokens have short time to live: OAuth is **not** an Authentication protocol. For the documentation, I suggest you to drop this approach (which is truly error prone) and go for an alternative documentation mechanism like Swagger using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle).